# Iterating through Class object list attribute

Tags: python, oop, kosaraju-algorithm

Hoping someone has some insight here.
First half of the Kosaraju algorithm implementation with a graph and node class.
I'm Iterating through a list of nodes each with a list of heads and a list of tails to allow moving forwards or backwards.
As you move through a Graph a newly explored vertex is `explored` and then you access the `head_list`:

```
    for j in i.head_list:
        DFS(my_graph, j, T, S)
```

What is interesting is that `i.head_list` is sometimes an empty list although in the Graph **Test Data** every nodes has at least one head and one tail.

Example (from **Test Data** below): first call should be '9' with a `head_list` of [6] but [] is returned and the `tail_list` is [3, 7]. In debugging drilling into into variable 3 as part of th `tail_list`, `head_list` is populated with [9] but `tail_list` is []. Sort of flip flopping between populating head and tail lists.

I thought there was some global variable mix up but I haven't found it. I thought maybe copy.deepcopy might have fixed it but it's not that. It just seems vey unusual behavior. What is even more interesting is that it only seems to produce an empty list when a node has already been included in a `head_list`. For example: Node 4 is the first fails and

I expected to be able to drill continuously through nodes and `head_list`'s or `tail_list`'s indefinitely but the presence of the lists in iteration changes bank and forth. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Test Data**

| Node | Tail |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 9 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 8 | 6 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 9 | 7 |

````
class Graph():

    def __init__(self, graph):
        self.graph = graph
        self.node_list = []
    def add_node(self, node):
        self.node_list.append(node)


    def __repr__(self):
        return (f'_{self.graph} + {[node for node in self.node_list]} + {[node.head_list for node in self.node_list]}')

class Node():

    def __init__(self, head):
        self.head = head
        self.explored = False
        self.head_list = []
        self.tail_list = []
        self.leader = None
        self.finish_time = 0
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.head}'
    def add_node_edge(self, Node, lst):
        if lst == 'head':
            self.head_list.extend([Node])
        else: 
            self.tail_list.extend([Node])

def DFS_loop(my_graph):
    global T
    global S
    T = 0 # number of nodes processed so far
    S = None # current source vertex

    for node in my_graph.node_list[::-1]:
        if node.explored == False:
            S = node
            DFS(my_graph, node, T, S)

def DFS(my_graph, i, T, S):

    i.explored = True
    i.leader = S.head

    for j in i.head_list:
        DFS(my_graph, j, T, S)
    T += 1
    i.finish_time = T

file1 = open('C:/Downloads/test_Data.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()

my_graph = Graph('A')

default_node = Node(0)
my_graph.node_list = [default_node]*9
unexplored_queue = []

for line in Lines:
    h, t = line.strip().split()
    h = int(h)
    t = int(t)
    new_node = Node(h)
    new_head_node = Node(h)
    new_tail_node = Node(t)

    new_node.add_node_edge(new_tail_node, 'tail')
    new_tail_node.add_node_edge(new_node, 'head')

    if my_graph.node_list[h-1].head == 0:
        my_graph.node_list[h-1] = new_node
    else:
        my_graph.node_list[h-1].add_node_edge(new_tail_node, 'tail')

    if my_graph.node_list[t-1].head == 0:
        my_graph.node_list[t-1] = new_tail_node
    else:
        my_graph.node_list[t-1].add_node_edge(new_node, 'head')

DFS_loop(my_graph)
for node in my_graph.node_list:
    print(node, node.finish_time)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
new_node = Node(h)
new_head_node = Node(h)
new_tail_node = Node(t)
```

you are assuming that the tail node does not already exist in the graph.  That's not a safe assumption.  If the tail node already exists, you need to adjust its links, not assign a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim who got me thinking more clearly about this. In my original code the head and tail lists are a list of node objects. But if you don't use the node already in the graph then you don't correctly include all the tail and head nodes and updating the node's head and tail lists is a nightmare.

I updated the code to index the position in the graph the head or tail refers to now. The `node.head_list` and `node.tail_list` become a list of integers that you call with `my_graph.node_list[node.head_list[0]]`

```
    new_node = Node(h)
    new_tail_node = Node(t)

    if my_graph.node_list[h-1].head == 0:
        my_graph.node_list[h-1] = new_node
        my_graph.node_list[h-1].tail_list.append(t)
    else:
        my_graph.node_list[h-1].tail_list.append(t)

    if my_graph.node_list[t-1].head == 0:
        my_graph.node_list[t-1] = new_tail_node
        my_graph.node_list[t-1].head_list.append(h)
    else:
        my_graph.node_list[t-1].head_list.append(h)
```